# How do I call a WCF Service from an Oracle Trigger

Tags: wcf, oracle, service

I have written a WCF Service that executes an SSIS package to replicate some data and need to call it from an Oracle Trigger after Insert.  I do not handle the back end and have never attempted anything like this before.  Would someone please tell me how I can call a method inside of a WCF Service via a trigger in Oracle.

This is how the higher ups want it to be done and I do not have any design authority in how it is suppose to work.  Getting WCF to talk to SQL Server SSIS is no problem, it's how to call the WCF Service from Oracle that is a nightmare. How can I tackle this? I am not a seasoned Oracle person at all.

Comment: Have a look into utl_dbws to call web services from Oracle.  Good article here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws-10g.php

Comment: Ok thanks tbone...I had a look at it and am going to see if anyone here can make sense of the oracle part.  All they need to do from Oracle is call the service and fire a method.  At this point I don't think any parameters need to be passed to the service.  If so I have an overloaded method that can accept parameters.  If I could make sense of the PL/SQL or knew Oracle better, it does appear this example should work.  Thanks again

Comment: np, if your Oracle devs can't get it working, post a follow-up and we'll see what can be done.

Comment: Hi tbone, and thank you again.  Our DBA is going to run the commands to get the UTL_DBWS package installed on our Dev server for me but I'm having to try to decipher the Oracle code and am having problems with the function.  It's easy to call a function from a trigger but inside the function all I need to do is call a WCF Service that's called OracleToDB2 and call a method called ExecutePackage.  I'm not sure what some of the variables are for like i_wsdl_url, l_namespace       , l_service_qname, l_port_qname, and l_operation_qname.  I'm not sure how to use these.  Would you mind telling me?

Comment: Take a look at the oracle-base link again, and refer to the associated soap wsdl here: http://www.oracle-base.com/webservices/server.php?wsdl You should be able to relate this basic example to your specific situation.  Try for yourself first, should be straight forward.